# How to show notifications only from launcher in kiosk mode (lock task) android 11

Tags: java, android, android-11, kiosk-mode, kiosk

I'm developing a launcher in android 11 which use lock task but this function hide all status bar notifications, if the launcher isn't in task mode, the notification launcher can be seen.
How can I show the launcher notifications?